# Make popup div stackable

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Hi all I have this popup that im inserting into the main div via function. Everything works okay if I call it only once, but what I want to do is to call it on every error so that every error has its own popup. If I do that now every popup is overlaying.

How can I make this popup stackable so they can be under each other if there is more than one?

The code is here

https://jsfiddle.net/s86nw4ct/6/

note I'm not using any frontend framework

```js
let timer1, timer2;
const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper')



function showPopUp(title, body) {
  const popup_data =
    `<div class="toast active">
            <div class="toast-content">
                <i class="fas fa-solid fa-check check"></i>
                <div class="message">
                    <span id="text_title" class="text text-1">${title}</span>
                    <span id="text_body" class="text text-2">${body}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark close"></i>
            <div class="progress active"></div>
        </div>`

  wrapper.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', popup_data);

  const toast = document.querySelector(".toast");
  (closeIcon = document.querySelector(".close")),
  (progress = document.querySelector(".progress"));
  toast.classList.add("active");
  progress.classList.add("active");

  timer1 = setTimeout(() => {
    toast.classList.remove("active");
  }, 5000);

  timer2 = setTimeout(() => {
    progress.classList.remove("active");
  }, 5300);

  closeIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
    toast.classList.remove("active");

    setTimeout(() => {
      progress.classList.remove("active");
    }, 300);

    clearTimeout(timer1);
    clearTimeout(timer2);
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}


/*popup part */

.toast:not(.showing):not(.show) {
  /*bootsratp overide */
  opacity: 1;
}

.toast {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 25px;
  right: 30px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px 35px 20px 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateX(calc(100% + 30px));
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.35);
}

.toast.active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.toast .toast-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.toast-content .check {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 35px;
  min-width: 35px;
  background-color: #4070f4;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.toast-content .message {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.message .text {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #666666;
}

.message .text.text-1 {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #333;
}

.toast .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.toast .close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.toast .progress {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
}

.toast .progress:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4070f4;
}

.progress.active:before {
  animation: progress 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
  100% {
    right: 100%;
  }
}

button {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background-color: #4070f4;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #0e4bf1;
}

.toast.active~button {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div id="wrapper">
  <button type="button" onclick="showPopUp('test','body')">test</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that all `.toast.active` divs have the same absolute position. You could use JS to position the next `.toast` not at the same `top: 25px` but below the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could identify each toaster uniquely by using a counter and an Id for each new toaster, and use it to adjust the position of each one. In this code, I am querying all active toasters to know how far down I should put a new one. And when a toaster times out, it selects all the other ones and push them up.

```
let timer1, timer2;
const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper')
let counter = 0;
let distance = 80;

function updateToastPosition(){
  let allToasts = document.querySelectorAll(".toast");
  allToasts.forEach(element =>{
    let pos = parseInt(element.style.top.split("px")[0]);
    element.style.top = (pos-distance) + "px";
  });
}

function showPopUp(title, body){
    const popup_data = 
        `<div id="toast_${counter}"class="toast active">
            <div class="toast-content">
                <i class="fas fa-solid fa-check check"></i>
                <div class="message">
                    <span id="text_title" class="text text-1">${title}</span>
                    <span id="text_body" class="text text-2">${body}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark close"></i>
            <div class="progress active"></div>
        </div>`
    
    wrapper.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', popup_data);  
    const toastElement = document.getElementById("toast_"+counter);
    
    let allToasts = document.querySelectorAll(".toast.active");
    toastElement.style.top = 25 + (allToasts.length - 1) * distance + "px";

    //const toast = document.querySelector(".toast");
    const closeIcon = document.querySelector(`#toast_${counter} > .close`);
        const progress = document.querySelector(`#toast_${counter} > .progress`);
    toastElement.classList.add("active");
    progress.classList.add("active");
        console.log("123");
    timer1 = setTimeout(() => {
        toastElement.classList.remove("active");
                updateToastPosition();
    }, 5000);

    timer2 = setTimeout(() => {
        progress.classList.remove("active");
    }, 5300);

    closeIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
        toastElement.classList.remove("active");

        setTimeout(() => {
            progress.classList.remove("active");
        }, 300);
                updateToastPosition();
        clearTimeout(timer1);
        clearTimeout(timer2);
    });
    counter++;
}
```

JsFiddle working example: https://jsfiddle.net/rw4c3a9z/1/

Edit: Now the close button should work as well, I changed the selector to only get the close button and progress bar that are inside a specific toast.

Comment: this is exactly what I was trying to achieve but in a more elegant way, now to figure out how to make them close by clicking x button

Comment: @rafaelHTML I changed the code a little bit and updated the link, now the x button should work.

Comment: If I create 3 toasts, closing the middle toast seems to scoot all the toasts upwards and offscreen.

Comment: if anyone is using it put toastElement.remove() inside timer2 behind classList removal. Cleans out the dom from old popups

Answer (score 2):

You have every `.toast` element at the exact same absolute position, so you are stacking them all on top of each other.  A better way to do this is to have a wrapping/container element for all the toast elements.  You set the absolute position of this, and then just add the toast elements inside of that, and they do not need to have any positioning on them, they can just have the standard block level element stacking.

```js
let timer1, timer2;
const wrapper = document.getElementById('toast-container')

function showPopUp(title, body) {
  const popup_data =
    `<div class="toast active">
            <div class="toast-content">
                <i class="fas fa-solid fa-check check"></i>
                <div class="message">
                    <span id="text_title" class="text text-1">${title}</span>
                    <span id="text_body" class="text text-2">${body}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark close"></i>
            <div class="progress active"></div>
        </div>`

  wrapper.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', popup_data);

  const toast = document.querySelector(".toast");
  (closeIcon = document.querySelector(".close")),
  (progress = document.querySelector(".progress"));
  toast.classList.add("active");
  progress.classList.add("active");

  timer1 = setTimeout(() => {
    toast.classList.remove("active");
  }, 5000);

  timer2 = setTimeout(() => {
    progress.classList.remove("active");
  }, 5300);

  closeIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
    toast.classList.remove("active");

    setTimeout(() => {
      progress.classList.remove("active");
    }, 300);

    clearTimeout(timer1);
    clearTimeout(timer2);
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}


/*popup part */

#toast-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 25px;
  right: 30px;
}

.toast:not(.showing):not(.show) {
  /*bootsratp overide */
  opacity: 1;
}

.toast {
  border-radius: 12px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px 35px 20px 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateX(calc(100% + 30px));
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.35);
}

.toast.active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.toast .toast-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.toast-content .check {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 35px;
  min-width: 35px;
  background-color: #4070f4;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.toast-content .message {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.message .text {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #666666;
}

.message .text.text-1 {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #333;
}

.toast .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.toast .close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.toast .progress {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
}

.toast .progress:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4070f4;
}

.progress.active:before {
  animation: progress 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
  100% {
    right: 100%;
  }
}

button {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background-color: #4070f4;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #0e4bf1;
}

.toast.active~button {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="toast-container"></div>
  <button type="button" onclick="showPopUp('test','body')">test</button>
</div>
```

Comment: that's working better than what i gor right now, what I was trying to do now is getting offsetHeight seeing how many elements I got and positioning them by calculating but this was so inefficient

Comment: btw do you know why only first popup is auto removing and the rest stays in place after time run out?

Comment: Yes, but I think it's been addressed by @Mystery's answer, the one you accepted.  Basically you are just keeping global timers, and every time you create a new toast you override that timer with the new one.